# `pythontex` and `\subfigure`

Tags: subfloats, python, pythontex

`pythontex` causing error with `\subfigure` environment.

I have to rewrite my dissertation with many figures and subfigures, of which some are plotted with python inside LaTeX (I had to give up the `python` package). When a subfigure is added `ptyhontex` complains, that

```
!

LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.

 (... cut ...)

l.20 \begin{subfigure}
                      {0.4\textwidth}
?
```

My minimal working example:

```
% !TEX options=--shell-escape

% Create subfigures in LaTeX
% https://latex-tutorial.com/subfigure-latex/

\RequirePackage{pythontex}  % when these
\setpythontexlistingenv{listingPtex}  % lines are commented, it compiles just fine

\documentclass[a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,12pt]{mwrep}


\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
        
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Firts subfigure.}
    \label{fig:first}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Second subfigure.}
    \label{fig:second}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Third subfigure.}
    \label{fig:third}
\end{subfigure}
        
\caption{Creating subfigures in \LaTeX.}
\label{fig:figures}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried to compile it with the `report` class, instead of `mwrep` -- didn't help. Changing `listingPtex` to `listing` neither.

There are at least a few solution for combining `python` and LaTeX -- perhaps it would be worth to take another approach? Have you got any suggestions?

Or should I try different approach to subfigures? Such one, that would work with `pythontex`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't load `pythontex` before `\documentclass`. Just fix the missing compatibility bit in `mwrep.cls` (it doesn't define `\@chapter`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,12pt]{mwrep}


\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter\providecommand\@chapter{}\makeatother

\usepackage{pythontex}
\setpythontexlistingenv{listingPtex}

\begin{document}
        
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Firts subfigure.}
    \label{fig:first}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Second subfigure.}
    \label{fig:second}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Third subfigure.}
    \label{fig:third}
\end{subfigure}
        
\caption{Creating subfigures in \LaTeX.}
\label{fig:figures}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've been trying to use LaTeX for some years now and, I must say, I've been struggling. Quite often I find myself in a situation when a new solution breaks what was written up to the point of its introduction. I was going in circles with figures, subfigures, captions and subcaptions, and pythontex seemed to complicate things even more.
So without much enthusiasm I tried to compile your example. I was simply shocked when it worked! Even more when I tried referencing figures and subfigures with \ref and

Comment: @khaz Do you *really* need `mwrep`?

Comment: 3) inserted some python snippets. Grazie mille @egreg.

Comment: I really don't know if I need it -- I have to contact the printing house -- you don't print dissertations by yourself, at my university (probably at no university). Is `report` much better? Less conflicts, I assume?